# Nginx: Serve URL path by different config file

Tags: nginx

I have 2 different application running on the server and both should be served by the same domain, let's say CMS1 will be served by domain.com while CMS2 served by domain.com/path

I have each CMS working properly by separated domains. But, I need in some way, when someone go to domain.com/path, nginx serve the site from CMS2.conf configuration file. while the main domain is served from the cms1.conf

I tried to have some configs in one file, but can't have location block inside another location block

Any advise?

Comment: "but can't have location block inside another location block" - yes you can, but there are some limitations. If you had posted the config you tried and the corresponing error messages you might have a more explicit answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

For using different config files, you could use nginx's `include` directive.

Addressing the question, using the same server block with multiple location blocks (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) could achieve this by serving based on path.

(Note: Would've asked for clarification or an example of what you've tried in a comment but don't have enough reputation yet.)

Comment: Welcome to SF. You could improve your answer and thus increasing the chance of getting upvotes by adding an example instead of just linking to the documentation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).